# How to fix "ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap" on a Tomcat 7 server?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

The latest versions of Chrome and Firefox have disabled SSLv3.0 by default, due to the [POODLE vulnerability](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A).   This leads to the following error when I attempt to open a site I have set up (and which was working fine):

With Chrome:

```
A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an unsupported protocol.
Error code: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

With Firefox:

```
Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
```

I have researched this issue [with Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451311), [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547219/firefox-ssl-error-no-cypher-overlap-error), [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) and [more Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_BIO_and_NIO).  I understand the problem, but I can't find the documentation to configure Tomcat 7 to use only the TLS ciphers and protocols that are now safe.   I'm not sure if I need to create a new cert/keypair, change my server.xml, or install a new version of Tomcat, or what.   I'm not even sure what versions of cipher/protocol are now considered "acceptable" by these browsers.   Can anyone point me to the docs or an example setup for this?

I'm using OpenJDK 1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Tomcat 7.

Here's my cert file (redacted):

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: something
Creation date: May 4, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=something, OU=something, O=something, L=something, ST=something, C=something
Issuer: CN=something, OU=something, O=something, L=something, ST=something, C=something
Serial number: ...
Valid from: Sat May 04 17:28:21 MST 2013 until: Tue May 02 17:28:21 MST 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  ...
     SHA1: ...
     SHA256: ...
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
     Version: 3
```

Here's my `server.xml` entry for HTTPS support:

```
<Connector port="8484" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/path/mykeystore"  
           keystorePass="password"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLS" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to widen `sslEnabledProtocols` to include TLSv1 &ff, depending on your Java version.

You specify ciphers with the [`ciphers` element of the connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).

Nothing to do with the certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your response - but what are the actual values required for each field, though?   For example, for `sslEnabledProtocols` I have tried "TLS", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" and "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" with no success.   I don't get any error messages in the Tomcat log, but the browser(s) still will not connect.

Comment: Try `sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"` as described in https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE

Comment: I actually wound up generating a new self-signed certificate and that solved the problem.   I have no idea why the old one stopped working but thank you, I'm marking your answer correct.

Comment: Having same problem.  It is nowhere mentioned here _WHICH_ ciphers I should mention in the ciphers attribute.  adding the sslEnabledProtocols attribute alone (with the specified value) isn't enough.

Answer (score 16):

I had the problem on a new installation using Tomcat 8.0.23 and Java 8 build 1.8.0_45.  I finally discovered that I had failed to specify the **-keyalg RSA** option when I created my self signed certificate with the Java keytool utility.  I deleted the old key store and made sure to include that option when I made a new keystore.  That fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting this error in chrome until I added the RSA flag to look something like this: keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keypass localhost -keystore certificates.keystore -storepass localhost -keyalg RSA

Comment: Thanks @MrZcxfph

Your fix enabled me to get TLS working on Fedora 24 + Tomcat 8.0.36 + Java 1.8.0_111 after half a day of frustrations

Comment: after I tried everything on internet for 1 day, this helped me. Also tnx @false_memories for the example command

Comment: Thanks.
@false_memories +1 for example

Answer (score 3):

The complete Tomcat server.xml Connector element:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" />
```

This works for me, I am using JRE1.7 and Tomcat7 server also. But setting `sslEnabledProtocols` not work for me, here using sslProtocol="TLS" instead, and specify the ciphering algorithm explicitly.