# AWS Tomcat SSL browser errors - what have I missed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, https, bitnami

I'm attempting to set up TLS (SSL) with my domain hosted on AWS Bitnami so that users can access it over HTTPS. It is running on Apache Tomcat standalone and is not fronted by a LB.

To generate the Certificate Signing Request (CSR) I have:

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf/server.key 2048
```

And entered all the correct information i.e. hostname in www.hostname.com format, then:

```
sudo openssl req -new -key /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf/server.key -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr
```

Following that I have copied to the .csr file contents to the CA (ssl.comodo.com) & saved the resulting files: .ca-bundle and .crt file.

Following that I have uploaded the files to the Tomcat directory and loaded them into the Java keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file www_domainname_com.ca-bundle -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

and the .crt:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file www_domainname_com.crt -keystore KeyStore.jks
```

Tomcat is configured to use this keystore with the following config in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="/home/bitnami/KeyStore.jks" keystorePass="passwordhere" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Then apache has been restarted. The browser errors that I receive are:

Chrome:

> uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Firefox:

> no common encryption algorithm(s). Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

**My thoughts**

Based on this Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449966/how-to-fix-ssl-error-no-cypher-overlap-on-a-tomcat-7-server) I think this may have something to do with RSA - when I generate a new keystore with the `-keyalg RSA`parameter:
`$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA` and point the Tomcat `server.xml` SSL config to that the site loads over HTTPS and I get warnings in the browser telling me that it is a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate using OpenSSL, you must then convert the PRIVATE KEY AND certificate chain, *not just the certificate(s) alone*, to a Java-usable keystore, either PKCS12 or JKS.

If you want to generate using Java, you do use `keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA` (and before j7 add `-keysize 2048`), *then* you use Java `keytool` to generate the CSR which you give to the CA (Comodo), and you use Java `keytool` to import the new cert and its chain from the CA.

See the options at (my) https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423399/2868801 and several additional dupes linked there.